# Keep two Macports installations in sync

Tags: macports

I've got two Macs, an iMac and a Macbook Pro. I do web development work on both, my data is synced with a local cloud solution. But how do I keep my Macports installations in sync? At the moment I try two manually install the very same packages, but with all the port variants I'd hope for a more sophisticated solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output of `port echo active` to a file on one machine, sync the output to the other machine, and run `port install` for each line.

That would be just the most naive solution, mainly not handling "merge conflicts".